# NSDateComponents doesn't return date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get data from 2 variables: `hours = "08"` and `minutes = 30`. I am doing it this way:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.hour = hours.toInt()!
components.minute = minutes.toInt()!
let neededDate = components.date
```

But `neededDate` is nil. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use NSDateComponents in this direction you have to set the calendar.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let components = NSDateComponents()

components.calendar = calendar // Add this line

components.hour = hours.toInt()!
components.minute = minutes.toInt()!
let neededDate = components.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the date from calendar with the components:

```
let neededDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you fetch the value of `neededDate`. Now you are doing it in this way `let neededDate = components.date` where it is `nil` because the `components.date` is never assigned any value. So the code you need is as below.

```
let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
```

Hope this helps!